# Google Analytics API - extract information on Urls visited by users

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I started to use the Google Analytics API in order to import the necessary information into R. It is working nicely, but I miss one important piece of information: in the Google Analytics website, I can have a look at hits by the domain on my website (e.g. `/about`, `/data`), but I cannot find this information in the dimensions and metrics explorer on the Google developer website...

Does anyone know how to extract this information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by /about, /data?

Comment: "hits by the domain on my website" - that actually looks rather more like hits per page path (ga:pagePath in the API), not per domain.

Comment: sorry for being unprecise, but Eikes answer is what I searched for. `ga:pagePath`is the solution.

Comment: for some reason, I cannot mark this thread as solved. maybe because @DalmTo edited the question? Could you mark it please?